# How to update manifest file on ios pwa?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, updates, manifest.json

How can a change to the manifest file of a pwa, installed on ios, be applied?
Emptying the cache on the device doesn't work, rebooting the device doesn't work either. I've also tried adding a parameter to bust the cache, like so:

```
manifest.webmanifest?v=1
```

Other files can be updated without issue, but for the manifest the only solution seems to be to reinstall the pwa, which isn't very userfriendly.

Thanks!